# Ubuntu startup issue 18.04.3

Tags: boot, dual-boot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lontF.jpg

So at one point I tried to do an update on my system that dual boots and the standard load stopped working. The three things in the imgur folder are what happens when I try each of these options.

One I try to just do a regular boot, but as you can see the only thing that I ever see when that happens is that it goes all purple.

The second, I go to advanced options and whether I choose the first option or the third they both say loading initial ramdisk and then stays that way forever.

and the third, where I go to advanced options and then pick the 5th option seems to work properly.

I would love to hear some way to fix the rest of the linux startup options as I'm fairly new to Linux and do not know what the ramifications are of doing this other startup. (it is also kinda tedious and I would prefer not having to do that)

Thanks for all your help!
-Milo

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons that appear just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a blown `/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-74-generic` file.

Use the GRUB Advanced Options menu, boot to kernel 4.15.0-70-generic.

Login in and open the `terminal` application.

`ls -al /boot/initrd*` # observe the file sizes

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-74-generic` # recreate the file

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-72-generic` # recreate the file

`ls -al /boot/initrd*` # observe the new file sizes

`reboot` # boot back into the normal Ubuntu kernel

**Update #1:**

Let's check your file system...

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- and while you're booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start the `Disks` application, and get screenshot(s) of the SMART Data window. Edit the screenshots into your question, or post them at imgur.com and give me the URL.
- type `reboot`

Comment: Hey, I tried this and the sizes did seem to change but when I rebooted there was no change in the other boot methods, I still had to go to the .70-generic.

Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @macp92 give me a minute, and I'll update my answer with the next step in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: I haven't tried your updated solution yet, but will reply here as soon as I have. Thanks for being so helpful! (I have upvoted your answer but as I have under 15reputation it does not display it)

Comment: @macp92 You're very welcome!